# how to view a navbar menu when you hover over an element when using tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to make a navbar menu item by using tailwind, here is the some snippet of the code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <li class="w-22  hover:border-gray-700 border-transparent border-b-2 cursor-pointer">
        <a href="#">New & Featured</a>
        <ul class="absolute hidden left-2 mt-2 py-2 w-48 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-xl">
          <li class="block px-4 py-2 text-gray-800 hover:bg-indigo-600">Laptops</li>
          <li class="block px-4 py-2 text-gray-800 hover:bg-indigo-600"><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
          <li class="block px-4 py-2 text-gray-800 hover:bg-indigo-600"><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like that when I hover on the element **News & Features** the drop down element element is seen, when I hover out it should return to its default hidden.